# Refreshing page while changing routes, Vue.js spring SPA

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, kotlin

I'm trying to create aplication using Vue.js and Spring boot. After switching to a different route using Vue routing my page reloads. I'm using this pice of code to forward to my client side route.

```
@Controller
class FrontController {

    @GetMapping("/**/{path:[^\\.]*}")
    fun redirect(@PathVariable path: String): String {
        return "forward:/index.html"
    }
}
```

`index.js`

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/sad',
    name: 'AdminDashboard',
    component: AdminDashboard
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'UserList',
    component: UserList
  },
  {
    path: '/role/all',
    name: 'RoleList',
    component: RoleList
  },
  {
    path: '/course/all',
    name: 'CourseList',
    component: CourseList
  },
  {
    path: '/category/all',
    name: 'CategoryList',
    component: CategoryList
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

export default router
```

Here is a gif to show my problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLlOY.jpg. So ye I'm trying to get rid off that flashing when switching on different pages. It works fine on Microsoft Edge, but not on Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Please [edit] your title to something that describes the question you're asking or problem you're having. Your current title is nothing but a repetition of the tag information. If you remove that regurgitated tag info, your entire title is *SPA*. Your title should be clear and descriptive enough to have meaning to a future site user who is skimming through a list of search results trying to find a solution to a problem.  Thanks.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun redirect(@PathVariable path: String, e:event): String {
 e.preventDefault();
        return "forward:/index.html"
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, it's not working. It gives me:  Invoked method public abstract void org.w3c.dom.events.Event.preventDefault() is no accessor method!